# When give two encodings rise to the same notion of computability?

Tags: computability

To my understanding, the notion of Turing-computability of a partial map $ℕ_0 \dashrightarrow ℕ_0$ depends on the encoding of $ℕ_0$.

Say $Σ$ is an alphabet and $γ \colon Σ^\ast → ℕ_0$ is a bijection. A partial map $f\colon ℕ_0 \dashrightarrow ℕ_0$ is then called *computable* with respect to $γ$ if its conjugation $γ^{-1} ∘ f ∘ γ \colon Σ^\ast \dashrightarrow Σ^\ast$ is computable by a turing machine over the alphabet $Σ$.

So say we have two bijective encodings $Σ^\ast → ℕ_0$ called $γ$ and $γ’$. Give these encodings rise to the same notion of computability if both make some basic maps $ℕ_0 → ℕ_0$ computable?

For example, if the successor map $ℕ_0 → ℕ_0$ is computable with respect to both $γ$ and $γ’$, are then all computable maps $ℕ_0 \dashrightarrow ℕ_0$ with respect to $γ$ and $γ’$ the same?

This seems intuitive to me, yet I don’t know if it’s true.

Comment: I don't see any reason to expect it to be true.  As a thought experiment, imagine making $\gamma$ "computable" and $\gamma'$ "not computable", for some suitable notion of "computable".

Comment: I don't follow your first sentence. A function is a function, and it's either computable or not. I struggle to see what kind of (reasonable) encoding of the naturals would make an otherwise computable function uncomputable, and the other way around seems even weirder.

Comment: @Raphael I’m not excluding unreasonable encodings. Isn’t it the case, that if one defines computability of partial maps $ℕ_0 \dashrightarrow ℕ_0$ in terms of Turing machines, one implicitly uses an encoding $Σ^\ast → ℕ_0$ to do so? I’d guess that people hide this issue of dependence on encodings under the term “reasonable” encoding (well, and of course, there are canonical encodings for bijections $Σ → \{0,…,b-1\}$), but I’m very interested in that! Or is it the case that it doesn’t depend on the encoding at all? I can’t imagine.

Comment: @D.W. You mean setting $γ’ = χ ∘ γ$ for some bijective map $χ \colon ℕ_0 →ℕ_0$ that is not computable with respect to $γ$? It might be the case that conjugating by $χ$ respects computability, i.e. for a computable map $f$ with respect to $γ$, the conjugate $χ^{-1} ∘ f ∘ χ$ might be computable with respect to $γ$ again.

Comment: I guess I don't see why it's interesting to see what happens to a notion of computability if your input encoding is not computable. (Feels circular, anyway.)

Comment: @Raphael Yes, what does it mean for an input encoding to be computable? I keep bumping into that statement, but what does it mean?

Comment: Where do you encounter that? Please give a quote with sufficient context!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36226/discussion-between-k-stm-and-raphael).

Comment: @Raphael For example, you yourself wrote “… if your input encoding is not computable.” How can an encoding be computable or not computable? How would you define that?

Comment: @k.stm The set of all legal inputs is a language; is it decidable?

Comment: @Raphael I don’t know what a legal input is.

Comment: Say the objects your problem talks about are weighted graphs. If the encoding of graphs is such that no TM can even decide if the input encodes a graph, of what use is that encoding?

Comment: @Raphael There are many useless encodings, yes. But I know of no rigorous definition of a *useless* encoding. For example, any *bijection* $Σ^* → \mathrm{Graph}$ (just like assumed in my question) makes the language of “all legal inputs” decidable (by being $Σ^*$ itself), so this is no good criterion. Mathematically, the definition of computability seems to highly depend on the encoding and I basically seek a way to make it mathematically independent by specifying what we expect of an encoding. (In my question, I was exploring the idea of something like a generating system of computable maps.)